# Looking for ways to add new nodes to Service Fabric development cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I remember I had 5 nodes in my local development SF Cluster from the moment I installed Service Fabric SDK on my machine. Then at some point of time I notices it had only one:

[image]

Now I can't find a way to add 2 more nodes back to my cluster. All the articles I can find are about standalone or Azure cluster and usually they say the approach does not work for dev cluster like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes

Any idea on how came 5 nodes happened to be one? How to add more nodes on dev cluster?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster#one-node-and-five-node-cluster-mode

Comment: oh, that's exactly what I need. I'd suggest to post that information as an answer, so I can mark it as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the mode to one-node cluster or a 5 node cluster, select Switch Cluster Mode in the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager. You can find it in the windows tray:

[image: enter code here]